# Emacs Scala Ensime: Opening REPL does not load anything from my project

Tags: scala, emacs, ensime

I am pretty sure I have setup Emacs, Ensime, SBT, and Scala to work together properly. I am able to edit files and see type errors when I save and have successfully tried using ensime's autorefactoring tools.

The problem is when I open a REPL by pressing `C-c C-v z` it seems as if nothing from my file is loaded.

In other words if I define something like

`class Moose {}`

in my source file, this is what happens when I try to use `Moose` from the REPL

```
scala> Moose
<console>:8: error: not found: value Moose
              Moose
              ^

scala> new Moose
<console>:8: error: not found: type Moose
              new Moose
                  ^
```

What is the best way to load something, such as the current buffer contents into the REPL?

Comment: Have you [set the `:target` directive correctly](http://aemoncannon.github.io/ensime/#tth_sEc4.4)?

Comment: @Chris I generated my `.ensime` file with `ensime generate` from `sbt`. `:target` is set to `"/home/user/testProject/target/scala-2.10/classes"`. How can I tell if this is correct or not?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if your classes are being compiled to that directory I suspect it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there was actually no problem with the REPL. I had been trying to compile my project by pressing `C-c C-b b` and assumed it was working the buffer `*ENSIME-Compilation-Result*` would pop up with:

```
Latest Compilation Results (q to quit, TAB to jump to next error)
----------------------------------------

0 errors, 0 warnings.
```

But, I checked in the `target/scala-2.10/classes` directory and found that no `.class` files were being generated.

When I instead compiled from the command line with `sbt`, I was able to then get a REPL loaded with what I expected.

**EDIT**:

I posted a follow-up question: [Building with Ensime deletes all .class files, but doesn't compile anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565975/building-with-ensime-deletes-all-class-files-but-doesnt-compile-anything).